# Map from inner property to destination class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have automapper profile

Here is mappings

```
 CreateMap<CompaniesHouseMatchResult, InputCompaniesHouseSearchResult>()
        .ForMember(x => x.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => aa.CompaniesHouseItem.Title))
        .ForMember(x => x.CompanyNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => aa.CompaniesHouseItem.CompanyNumber))
        .ForMember(x => x.CompanyStatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => aa.CompaniesHouseItem.CompanyStatus))
        .ForMember(x => x.CompanyStatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => aa.CompaniesHouseItem.CompanyStatus))
        .ForMember(x => x.CompanyStatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => aa.CompaniesHouseItem.CompanyStatus))
        .ForMember(x => x.JobId, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.SupplierKey, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.DateOfCessation, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.DateOfCreation, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.DateOfCreation, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.InputCompaniesHouseSicCodes, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.InputCompaniesHousePreviousNames, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Source class looks like this

```
  using Ptco.DataPipeline.Services.Matching;
using Ptco.DataPipeline.Services.Matching.Models;
using Ptco.External.CompanyHouseApi.Models.Response;

namespace Ptco.DataPipeline.Services.Services.CompaniesHouse;

public record CompaniesHouseMatchResult(Item CompaniesHouseItem, MatchResult MatchResult);
```

So to match `CompanyName` I need to write

```
 .ForMember(x => x.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => aa.CompaniesHouseItem.Title))
```

How I can math it without specifying child?

Comment: Why do you think you can? If the data is coming from a child entity then why do you think that it's possible to access it without referring to that child entity? You would need to a different entity that already had that data at the top level in order to access it at the top level.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html